# How can I detect what occupied the disk space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space-utilization

I have my external disk mounted in `/log` and I'm not able to write into it anymore because it's full. When I check with `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G   12K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           748M  384K  748M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.4G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        40G   49M   38G   1% /mnt
/dev/xvdc        40G   38G  4.0K 100% /log
```

But with `df -i` it's only 1%:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            956199    394  955805    1% /dev
tmpfs           957438    328  957110    1% /run
/dev/xvda1      524288 165951  358337   32% /
none            957438      2  957436    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            957438      1  957437    1% /run/lock
none            957438      1  957437    1% /run/shm
none            957438      2  957436    1% /run/user
/dev/xvdb      2621440     11 2621429    1% /mnt
/dev/xvdc      2621440  23593 2597847    1% /log
```

Using sudo `du -s /log/* |sort -n`:

```
4   /log/production.log
16  /log/lost+found
32  /log/redis
240024  /log/linsight
5008628 /log/mongodb
```

and finally I couldn't find what took up so much disk space by using `ncdu /log`:

```
    4.8GiB [##########] /mongodb                                                                                                                                                         
  234.4MiB [          ] /linsight
   32.0KiB [          ] /redis
!  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
    4.0KiB [          ]  production.log
```

P/s: I think something is really wrong here, I'm 100% sure that `production.log` is GBs but it shows only 4.0KB here.

Answer (score 1):

`du -s /log/* /log/.??*|sort -n` will show you what takes the most space and you can reuse that same approach for the subdirectories that you find big to drill down your investigation.

When there is disk usage that is not accounted for in the file listing, it means that some program is still writing to a file that was removed.  The only way to free that space is to stop the program, which could be done by restarting the computer if you don't know what it is.  Since you mention that the `production.log` should be bigger, the process that generated it would be the first one to try restarting.

Note that `df -i` will show the inode usage which does not reflect disk space usage but the file count relative to its filesystem limit.

Comment: I will add the output into my question

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your results.

Comment: Ah i didnt know it. Let me see

Comment: try lsof |grep deleted to see file which are removed but still opened

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can simply do `ls -lh` and it will provide you a human readable result.

Also like this `ls /path/to/tmp -lh`

Comment: I don't think `ls -lh` would show anything better than using `ncdu`, i also used it as you suggested but nothing new.

Comment: @vutran Sorry it didn't help. But the command should be able to give you an idea in GB, MB and KB formats, of what's directories and files are utilizing the storage space. And start from there.

Comment: I just updated my question, please check it out.